# Cannot assign to property: 'myObject<MyProtocol>' is a 'let' constant - For nullable property under @optional in MyProtocol

Tags: swift, objective-c, option-type, swift-protocols

I have an Objective C legacy protocol - `MyProtocol` and class `MyObject` confirming to `MyProtocol`. I've added a new `_Nullable` property under `@optional` section in MyProtocol. When I'm trying to set a new value for the property, from Swift code, I'm getting the error - `Cannot assign to property: 'myObject' is a 'let' constant`, but working fine for other `required` properties.

In MyProtocol,

```
@optional
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber * _Nullable newProprty;
```

From Swift class,

```
myObject. newProprty = someNewValue // Compilation error
```

When I checked, looks like `newProprty` is showing as a `double-optional` property: `newProperty: NSNumber??`and I'm not able to write to such properties.

When I moved this property from @optional to required section in MyProtocol, everything started working fine. Just wondering is there any workaround to make it work as an optional property itself.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like `@optional` properties of type `T` are already imported as `T?` in Swift. So you might just want it to be `_Nonnull`, and have a single layer of optionality, introduced by the `@optional` section

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, that seems correct